# How to run a task that changes folders by itself

Tags: shell-script, thumbnails

I'd like to run VCS (Video Contact Sheet), a program that creates contact sheets (thumbnails) of video files.

This is the scenario: I have a root folder called **Temp**. Inside, I have many other folders named with years: 1991, 1992, 1993, etc. In each *year-folder* I have other sub-folders with the title of the videos. Here is an example:

```
Temp --> This is a folder
|
|
 1995  --> This is a folder
 |  
 |   
  Vacation in Italy  --> This is folder
  |
  |
   Video 1.mp4
   Video 2.mp4
   Video 3.mp4
   Video 4.mp4
   Video 5.mp4
```

My objective is:

1. Create a folder called **Screens** at the same level of the videos.
2. Make the command vcs to start from Temp, and make the thumbnails of all my videos inside the folder **Screens**. All videos are **MP4s**. All thumbnails are **JPGs**.

The command to make a thumbnail of a video is:

```
vcs /home/user/Temp/1991/"Vacation in Italy"/"Video 1.mp4" -U0 -n 15 -c 3 -H 200 -a 300/200 -j
```

Do you have any idea on how to automatize all of this?

Comment: So `Screens` should be inside `Vacation in Italy`? And it should contain the output of the `vcs` command? Does `vcs` create its thumbnails in the current directory where it's run?

Comment: @roaima Yes, and Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script iterates across the set of `mp4` files that you have. It requires an absolute path to each, so that `vcs` can find the video file reliably.

```
for mp4 in ~/Temp/*/*/*.mp4
do
    dir="$(dirname "$mp4")"
    screen="$dir/Screen"

    if test ! -d "$screen"
    then
        echo "Processing videos in $dir" >&2
        mkdir -p "$screen"
    fi
    ( cd "$screen" && vcs "$mp4" -U0 -n 15 -c 3 -H 200 -a 300/200 -j )
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for fd in `cat "\`ls\`"`; do
   cd ~/Temp/$fd
   for sbfd in `cat "\`ls\`"`; do
      mkdir ~/Temp/$fd/$sbfd/Screens;
      cd ~/Temp/$fd/$sbfd/Screens;
      vcs /home/user/Temp/$fd/$sbfd/*.mp4 -U0 -n 15 -c 3 -H 200 -a 300/200 -j;
      done;
done;
```

If it doesn't work, tell me what (if any) error messages are given, and I will attempt to patch it for you. I can't test it on my machine, but in theory I think it should be OK.

You'll want to save that as a shell script by the way, and it will only work if Temp is in your home directory.

Comment: ``cat "\`ls\`"``? Eurgh. Please consider using `find -name '*.mp4'` instead.

Comment: Sorry 'bout the ugly code, but it's what I could put together quickly. It's been a while since I last did any significant amount of shell scripting, so I've probably gotten more than a bit rusty.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts! It doesn't work unfortunately. It prints a cat of my home folder content.